# Routes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I'm pretty new to AngularJS and have a little obstacle and wondered if anyone could push me in the right direction.

I am using as part of my routing system for the application a template I have created and then dynamically generate the url with an id taken from specific parts of objects in my controller here is an example:

```
{
   id: 'started',
   title: 'Get Started',
   image: 'assets/img/enrolment.jpg',
   system: 'eLP',
   pdf: 'assets/files/getting_started.pdf',
   info: 'blah blah blah.'
 },
```

so as you can see, the first part of my object is called 'id' and I have it configured within  my $routeProvider as:

```
$routeProvider.

            when('/',
                    {
                templateUrl: 'sessions/guides.html',
                controller: 'tutsList'
            }).
            when('sessions/:id',
                    {
                templateUrl: 'sessions/help.html',
                controller: 'tutsList'
            }).
            otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});
```

(guides.html is working, but help.html is coming back blank currently).

When I hover over the links within list that's generated, I can see the id is now coming through and showing up at the bottom of the page, but the link goes through to a blank template. I am aware that I have to add  a controller, which then sticks the id to the $routeParams , but, it doesn't seem to work when I use the phoneApp example process in AngularJS Docs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does the link look like?

Comment: <a href="#/sessions/{{ guide.id }}">See Help Guide</a> - this is how the link is written. The id is found within a list of objects called "guides" - thus ng-repeat="guide in guides" blah blah blah...

Comment: Your second `when` uses an absolute url. Try using a relative url -- `when('/sessions/:id',`

Comment: so.... when('/:id',... ? Is this what you mean?

Comment: nope, this didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If your using an android phone, don't you have to specify the directory path from the root directory? (not like appeared to have done for windows (  pdf: 'assets/files/getting_started.pdf'))

Sorry I'm fairly new to this myself.

Comment: this link: <a href="#/sessions/{{ guide.id }}">See Help Guide</a> - needs to pick up a template i have created an draw in some data that i choose from that object, so I am needing to find out what I am missing; as it almost seems there.